# Does 200 mean the request successfully started or successfully finished?

Tags: http

I realize this might sound like an odd question, but I'm seeing some odd results in my network calls so I'm trying to figure out if perhaps I'm misunderstanding something.

I see situations where in isolated incidents, when I'm uploading data, even though the response is 200, the data doesn't appear on the server. My guess is that the 200 response arrives during the initial HTTP handshake and then something goes wrong after the fact. Is that a correct interpretation of the order of events? Or is the 200 delivered once the server has collected whatever data the sending Header tells it is in the request? (cause if so then I'm back to the drawing board as to how I'm seeing what I'm seeing).

Comment: It should be returning status code 201, created. Or 202 accepted.

Comment: I personally have encountered `200` responses with blank/empty responses when attempting cross-domain AJAX requests. There is a web server setting that will permit serving context to cross-domain AJAX requests. May or may not be relevant to your use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means it has been successfully finished. From the [HTTP /1.1 Spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

```
10.2.1 200 OK

The request has succeeded. The information returned with the response is dependent on the method used in the request, for example:

GET an entity corresponding to the requested resource is sent in the response;

HEAD the entity-header fields corresponding to the requested resource are sent in the response without any message-body;

POST an entity describing or containing the result of the action;

TRACE an entity containing the request message as received by the end server.
```

Comment: yeah, unfortunately that's what I thought, though that really is confusing cause what I'm seeing is that I'm sending a file to the server (to a php listener) from my Android app, and then I delete the file when I get a 200 response from the server... however, 1/~100 times the file doesn't ever appear on the server.  I realize that I can do a secondary confirmation with a checksum or whatnot, but I'm really perplexed as to how this can be happening. I was hoping that this was a flaky mobile network connection issue, and that the 200 was being received at the initial connection made.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel you delete the file on your android app or on the server? What is your content type on your HTTP call from the Android app?

Comment: that's correct. I don't have the code in front of me, but I set it up to be identical to a multipart upload from a browser. Is that not the right way to do it? It *does appear to work the vast majority of the time.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel The multipart upload would be correct, just want to ensure that everything else is setup correctly. Perhaps there is something that is in the PHP script that may be deleting the file or not truly saving it and saying it is saved?

Comment: It's an EXTREMELY simple php file (just a few lines) and there's really no place for it to fail. The files are always well within the size limit (they're generated by the app and many megabytes smaller than the limit set in the ini) and the response that comes back actually contains a string that Android checks against before deleting the client side file, and the file names are unique (millisecond based) so, I'm *really stumped as to what the heck can be causing it.  I guess I have no choice but to write a byte size checker. Not a huge deal, just bizarre why it would ever happen.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Could it be a filename issue? Good luck diagnosing it

Comment: Thanks much. If I find something useful I'll post it here.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: if you're creating temporary files, php has functions that will create temporary file atomically (prevents collision). Otherwise, Perhaps your script is killed before it can flush the file buffer?

Answer (score 2):

Finished. It doesn't make sense otherwise. Something might go wrong and the code could throw an error. How could the server send that error code when it already sent 200 OK.

What you experience might be lag, caching, detached thread running after the server sent the 200 etc.

Answer (score 1):

A success reply, like 200, is not sent until after server has received and processed the full request.  Error replies, on the other hand, may be sent before the request is fully received.  If that happens, stop sending your request.